# How to check element properties in iOS gui automation?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiview, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

All UI Automation [examples](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1646-how-to-use-uiautomation-to-create-iphone-ui-tests/) I've seen uses standard components whose state can be inspected with the JavaScript API using the `value()` method. This is a bit limiting. Lets say you want to check the color or alpha value and whatnot.

**How can I inspect the properties of a view?**

An example: a tap on a certain element should make it "selected". I'd like to perform a tap on it and then verify that isSelected is TRUE.

**Update:**

I found the [withPredicate()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009903-CH1-SW52) method which should do it in theory, except it seems to only trigger on `name` properties:

```
element.withPredicate("isSelected == YES")          // always fails
element.withPredicate("name matches 'my element'")  // works
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up with this approach which works for my purposes:

Let UIView.accessibilityValue return a JSON string with relevant properties:

```
- (NSString *)accessibilityValue
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"{'alpha':%f, 'isSelected':%@}", 
            self.alpha, self.isSelected ? @"true" : @"false"];
}
```

Then use eval() in the test code and check those properties. value() is shorthand for calling accessibilityValue:

```
var props = eval("(" + element.value() + ")");

if (props.isSelected) {
    UIALogger.logFail("Should not be selected");
}

UIATarget.localTarget().tap({"x":471, "y":337});

var props = eval("(" + element.value() + ")");

if (!props.isSelected) {
    UIALogger.logFail("Should be selected");
}
```