# How to get Button Highlighted status in iOS UIAutomation?

Tags: javascript, ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to get a button's status to see if it is highlighted or not, but I cannot find such method in  iOS `UIAutomation`, can anyone help?

I tried `button().value()`, but it return 1 if it is last accessed, and return null if it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIAutomation exposes only a limited set of properties as described in their [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/UIAutomationRef.pdf)

Out of the box, you can check stuff like isEnabled, isVisible, etc

You can check this SO post for tweaking stuff [How to check element properties in iOS gui automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504358/how-to-check-element-properties-in-ios-gui-automation)

Comment: That's a good idea. I manually set status by adding cell.accessibilityValue="xxx" in source code, and then call button.value() to get the status in JavaScript.

Comment: basically, you can manually set any value to accessibilityValue in source code, and the use it in JavaScript by .value() property.